# Creating a PersistentEntityResource for a list of entities

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Say I've got an entity class `Person` and a controller `PersonController`. I've got a custom REST endpoint I want to implement and can not use a `CrudRepository` method for.

This is what my `PersonController` looks like:

```
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PeopleRestResource peopleRestResource; //@RepositoryRestResource extending CrudRepository

    @GetMapping("/custom")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCustomPeople(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {
        Set<Person> people = stream(this.peopleRestResource.findAll().spliterator(), true)
                .filter(/*Filter logic*/)                
                .collect(toSet());      
        return ok(persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(people));
    }

}
```

This will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` with the message `PersistentEntity must not be null`. `people` will actually contain a set of 2 person objects so this error message was a bit confusing at first. However, I assume this message actually means `Set is not a persistent entity`, as if I were to return just one person, the code would run just fine.

```
@GetMapping("/custom")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCustomPeople(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {
    Person person = stream(this.peopleRestResource.findAll().spliterator(), true)
                    .filter(/*Filter logic*/)                
                    .findFirst()
                    .elseThrow(() => new IllegalStateException());


    return ok(persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toFullResource(person));
}
```

Is there a way to make use of the `PersistentEntityResourceAssembler` to construct a HAL resource for a list of entities?

Preferably I wouldn't want to construct a `Resources` object and constructing all the links myself.

Answer (score 1):

To return a list of entities you can use CollectionModel
https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html/#fundamentals. You can call toCollectionModel() on the PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.

```
@GetMapping("/custom")
public ResponseEntity<?> getCustomPeople(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler persistentEntityResourceAssembler) {
    List<Person> persons = this.peopleRestResource.findAll()
    return ok(persistentEntityResourceAssembler.toCollectionModel(persons));
}
```